# rsync include rules refuse to work

Tags: include, rsync, rules

I have researched this pretty thoroughly.  Everything that supposedly "works" doesn't for my case, so I thought I would ask here.

I have a directory tree that looks like:

```
root/
   CK1E/
      3DConformers/
      OtherStuff/
   PDE4B/
      3DConformers/
      OtherStuff/
   ...
```

I am trying to use an rsync command to retrieve the "3DConformers" subdirectories from each of these projects.

I am issuing a command of the form:

```
rsync -avz user@host:/path/to/root/ . --exclude "*" --include-from rules -v -v
```

I couldn't get general rules to work so I decided to use specific ones, focusing on the "CK1E" subdirectory.  I read conflicting reports as to whether leading or trailing slashes were desired/required by rsync, so I took the shotgun approach.  My current rules file looks like this:

```
    /CK1E
    /CK1E/
    /CK1E/3DConformers
    /CK1E/3DConformers/
    /CK1E/3DConformers/*
    CK1E
    CK1E/
    CK1E/3DConformers
    CK1E/3DConformers/
    CK1E/3DConformers/*
```

I get the following output from rsync.  Note that the "CK1E" directory is still getting ignored!

```
    receiving incremental file list
    [sender] add_rule(- *)
    [sender] add_rule(+ /CK1E)
    [sender] add_rule(+ /CK1E/)
    [sender] add_rule(+ /CK1E/3DConformers)
    [sender] add_rule(+ /CK1E/3DConformers/)
    [sender] add_rule(+ /CK1E/3DConformers/*)
    [sender] add_rule(+ CK1E)
    [sender] add_rule(+ CK1E/)
    [sender] add_rule(+ CK1E/3DConformers)
    [sender] add_rule(+ CK1E/3DConformers/)
    [sender] add_rule(+ CK1E/3DConformers/*)
    server_sender starting pid=2451269
    [sender] make_file(.,*,0)
    recv_file_name(.)
    ...
    [sender] hiding directory CK1E because of pattern *
    ...
    received 1 names
    recv_file_list done
    send_file_list done
    get_local_name count=1 .
    generator starting pid=27883
    delta-transmission enabled
    recv_generator(.,0)
    recv_generator(.,1)
    generate_files phase=1
    recv_files(1) starting
    send_files starting
    send_files(0, /path/to/root/.)
    recv_files(.)
    send_files phase=1
    recv_files phase=1
    generate_files phase=2
    send_files phase=2
    recv_files phase=2
    send files finished
    total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0
    recv_files finished
    generate_files phase=3
    generate_files finished

    sent 212 bytes  received 1578 bytes  275.38 bytes/sec
    total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
    _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1505): about to call exit(0)
```

Help?!

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of include/exclude rules is important: *the **first** include/exclude rule that matches the file is the one that matters.*

Your first rule is `--exclude="*"`, so you're excluding *everything*. You need to reorder your rules so that your include rule matches *before* your catch-all exclude rule.

This command should work:

```
rsync -avz user@host:/path/to/root/ . \
      --include "/CK1E/" \
      --include "/CK1E/3DConformers/" \
      --include "/CK1E/3DConformers/*" \
      --exclude "*"
```

You need to add the intermediate directories, as well as the files, because, if you don't mention them explicitly, the catch-all exclude rule will match them, and if the direct is excluded then so are the contents.

*(The `\` are not part of the command; they just indicate line continuation; your shell will do the right thing when you cut-and-paste.)*